# Count ways to express a number as sum of consecutive numbers

Tags: java

Count ways to express a number as sum of consecutive numbers. Say 21 , there are 3 ways to get it [1,2,3,4,5,6] , [6,7,8] and [10,11] .

While I was looking for some solutions on internet I came to code snippet which I am unable to understand . Or mathematical theory behind it . Though it gives a correct answer .

```
long countConsecutive(long num){
  long sumOfFirstIntegers = 3;        
  long count = 0;       

  for(long i = 2 ; sumOfFirstIntegers<=num; ++i){                         
    if((i%2==0)?(num%i==i/2): (num%i==0)){                      
      ++count;               
    }             
    sumOfFirstIntegers+=i+1;                    
  }           
  return count;          
}
```

Comment: That code doesn't even compile

Comment: It does compile, just replace `itr` with `i` @XtremeBaumer. However this looks like a mathematical question, not a Java question.

Comment: @PaulLemarchand well, as soon as anything needs to be changed for something to compile, it does not compile until that thing is changed. If a simple copy paste provides code that does not compile, one can say it does not compile. You can never be sure if it is intended or not

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I agree most of the time, although there it was pretty obvious.

Comment: @PaulLemarchand ther could have been a member variable, which would result in vastly different results. Thats why OP should always post a MCVE

Answer (score 1):

Independent of the maths, this here is probably the line causing you a headache:

```
if((i%2==0)?(num%i==i/2): (num%i==0)) {
```

one can rewrite that like:

```
bool condition;
if (i%2 == 0) {
  condition = num%i == i/2;
} else {
  condition = num%&i == 0;
}
if (condition) { ++count; }
```

So the [ternary operator](https://www.baeldung.com/java-ternary-operator) is used to select a boolean condition, and % is the [modulo operator](https://www.baeldung.com/modulo-java).

For the math behind all of that, I delegate to [geeksforce](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-ways-express-number-sum-consecutive-numbers/).

Answer (score 0):

This Program is written in Python
very simple formula I applied

Sum of Arithmetic Sequence Formula
When the Last Term is Given S = n⁄2 (a + L)

```
N=15
result=0
for start in range(1,N):
    cnt=1
    for end in range(start,N):
        sum1= cnt/2*(start+end)
        cnt=cnt+1
        if(sum1==N):
            result=result+1
            #print(start,end)
print(result)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).